# how do i customize the look of a Drupal 7 Node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created an Article in Drupal 7 and I want to customize how the content is displayed.

I am trying to modify the node.tpl.php, which gives you access to the $content variable, but this is a multidimensional array and I cannot extract the keys or values within it.

Is there a way of seeing inside $content to find out the exact value pairs that I need?

Or is there another way of customizing the display and output of Drupal 7 content?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the and enable the `devel` module, it gives you access to a very handy function `dsm` that will render a widget that lets you explore the contents of any variable or object. So in your `node.tpl.php` file: `dsm($content);` at the top will let you inspect the content. Usually you will want to create a custom `node-type.tpl.php` file e.g. `node-article.tpl.php` which is only applied to nodes of a certain type.

Comment: Completely amazing Finbarr, the devel module is awesome. So I would like to access the Title of the Article which is in $array --> body --> #object --> title
where #obect (Object)stdClass    how can I get the value of the article's title? is like this?: $content[body][#object][title]

Comment: BEWARE FOR XSS! You cannot -ever- just print anything without knowing where it has been. Most of the values you find with dsm are tainted and printing them will open up XSS security holes. You can only print values that are known to be escaped and filtered already (such as $content[#some_field][#view]) or escape them yourself with one of many filtering and escape helpers.